# Ubuntu keeps powering on and off

Tags: nvidia, system-installation

This is my first experience of LInux Ubuntu. Everything is installed but the system keeps shutting down and rebooting. It happens most with web browsers and i have tried them all and they are all the same so i am back to using 'Brave'. I have tried cleaning every part of my computer, it's new ram, power unit etc, when i go back onto Windows 10 on a stand alone disk it works fine, no issues.

I have a Gigabyte x79 up4 rev1.0, it is has 3 sata drives, 2x2tb and 1x500mb, processor is Intel i7 4960x, graphics card is Nvidia 1660 super with three display ports connected the display has been tried at all frequencies. I am currently running the open source driver after testing the nivida drivers but still the same problem.

It seems to be crashing with any video shown, you tube or anything, when brower becomes expanded it crashes. I trade for a living and use trading view, either as stand alone or through the browser.

It just keeps pwering down.

Can anyone help, i have tried two versions of Ubuntu but the same problem.

I just want to be part of Linux and the community but if i can't hold the shut downs then i am back to Windows.

Thanks in advance for you help or advice no matter how small

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; though mention of browsers would imply you're trying a Ubuntu Desktop.  What release did you try?  Which kernel stack (*default set by the ISO you installed*)... ie. you're missing useful details that help us gain an opinion; hardware & release details are required.  Did you explore logs looking for clues on why the restart? or crash?  Did RAMtest complete? Were crash logs appearing in /var/crash?  If new you won't understand some of this (*fair enough*) but release details are a start & whatever diagnosis you attempted...

Comment: Is it rebooting, shutting down, crashing, or going to sleep or just logging you out?   What are the symptoms that make you believe one of these?

Comment: desktop version, No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy   / it just shuts down and restarts...no  sleeping or hibernation

Comment: as far as logs are concerned i am brand new to this system so i still do not know my way around

Comment: This is a *Question and Answer* site (*not a forum*) so please add additional details to your question, such as release details. Cleaner questions attract more readers & you want all details in your question.  You also didn't specify if you're using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop etc. as they have different kernel stack defaults. You likely mean 22.04 Desktop, but it's best if you're specific. You can peruse logs using `journalctl` (*scan & look for prior to shutdown day/time for clues etc; treat it like any POSIX system for searching*)

Comment: WOW, great response